# Codename One Style Sheet Needs Constant Libraries Refreshing

Tags: css, codenameone

I have a new Android application, that uses CSS styling.

The style sheet is added through the CN1-settings. This has always worked in the past.

Now, whenever I make changes to the style of a component in the style-sheet, they don't reflect, unless I refresh the CN1-Libraries.

Am I missing something? Have there been changes to the process? I haven't used CN1 for a few month.

I am using Eclipse on Ubuntu Budgie 19.10.

For the console output, after changing the CSS file and saving it, the print output is as follows:

```
-cn1-compile-css:
        [java] Retina Scale: 1.0
        [java] Updating merge file /home/xxxxxx/eclipse-workspace/Test_A1/css/theme.css.merged
        [java] Input: /home/xxxxxx/eclipse-workspace/Test_A1/css/theme.css
        [java] Output: /home/xxxxxx/eclipse-workspace/Test_A1/src/theme.res
        [java] Acquiring lock on CSS checksums file /home/xxxxx/eclipse-workspace/Test_A1/.cn1_css_checksums...
        [java] Lock obtained
        [java] Releasing lock
        [java] CSS file successfully compiled.  /home/xxxxxx/eclipse-workspace/Test_A1/src/theme.res

jar:
        [echo] Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller
        [echo]          code size and wider device support
        [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/xxxxxx/eclipse-workspace/Test_A1/build/tmp
Trying to override old definition of task javac
       [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /home/xxxxxx/eclipse-workspace/Test_A1/build/tmp
         [jar] Building jar: /home/xxxxxx/eclipse-workspace/Test_A1/dist/Test_A1.jar
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

This is the console output when I run the script:

```
Found theme.css file.  Watching for changes...
Retina Scale: 1.0
CSS> Retina Scale: 1.0
CSS> Updating merge file /home/xxxxxx/eclipse-workspace/Test_A1/css/theme.css.merged
CSS> Input: /home/xxxxxxx/eclipse-workspace/Test_A1/css/theme.css
CSS> Output: /home/xxxxxxx/eclipse-workspace/Test_A1/src/theme.res
CSS> Acquiring lock on CSS checksums file /home/xxxxxx/eclipse-workspace/Test_A1/.cn1_css_checksums...
CSS> Lock obtained
CSS> File has not changed since last compile.
CSS> Releasing lock
CSS> CSS file successfully compiled.  /home/xxxxxx/eclipse-workspace/Test_A1/src/theme.res
CSS> null
```

What called my attention is that the output says :
    CSS> File has not changed since last compile.
even though it has.

Comment: This might be a regression with a recent CSS feature update. Can you check if something is printed to the console of the running simulator?
There should be output there about monitoring the CSS file for changes. I suggest filing an issue for this regardless

Comment: Hi, Shay. Thanks for your quick reply. I have edited my question and included the print output from the console. What called my attention is that the output says CSS> File has not changed since last compile, even though it has.

Comment: How do I file an issue?

Comment: @rainer This is the place to file an issue: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani, many thanks, Francesco ..... good to see you are still around :-)